# Is following grammar LR(0)?

Tags: compilers, parsers, lr-k

I know how to verify whether grammar is LR(0) or not. But this particular case is little tricky and hence the question.

> Grammar:
>
> $SL \rightarrow SL ; S \space | \space \epsilon$
>
> $S \rightarrow s$
>
> (Note: $SL$ is single non-terminal.)

Now, LR(0) automaton for this grammar is as follow:

[image]

Now my question is whether to consider entry $start \rightarrow SL.$ in $State_1$ as SR conflict.

Because I previously came to know that we don't consider conflicts due to augmented production.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually augmented the grammar. The augmented grammar has the production $$start\to SL\;\$$$

With that change, state 1 is not a reduction state and there is no conflict.

If you did not intend to augment the grammar, then it is not $LR(0)$, because the language does not have the prefix property. But that's not very useful, so normally we augment grammars, turning the language $L$ into $L\$$, where $\$$ is a symbol not in the the alphabet for $L$. Clearly the augmented language has the prefix property.

There's a reasonable explanation with references on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#Theory).

Comment: But we use $start \rightarrow SL$ as augmentation rule. Don't we?  And we reduce by this production when the lookahead symbol is $\$$ in case of SLR, LALR and CLR. So is it different for LR(0).

Comment: Wikipedia mentions augmentation rule like one in your answer but some other reference like Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools (2nd Edition) by Ullman mentions it like $start \rightarrow SL $. And I think here this distinction makes the grammar lr(0) or non-lr(0) if you use different augmentation rule.

Comment: @vimal: yes, the presentation in the Dragon book is a bit confusing. If you look at the actual algorithm for constructing an SLR parsing table (algorithm 4.8 in the edition I have, but I think yours has different numbering) you'll see that the augmented rule is handled specially. First, it's excluded from being a reduction in 2b, and then in 2c it's treated as though $\$$ were in the lookahead, although with an "accept" action rather than a shift. Those special case rules are exactly the same as augmenting the rule with $\$$ and then treating the reduction as an accept rather than the shift...

Comment: In practice, that saves a state. But it complicates the exposition. Since the Dragon Book was written for practitioners rather than theoreticians, the pragmatic approach is justifiable, I suppose. But the usual way of writing augmentation rules seems simpler.